# Download a .plist file

Tags: objective-c

Given I uploaded a .plist file to my online website (located at, dunno, www.example.com/data.plist), how do I download that .plist file to my iPhone application and read it successfully?

Comment: how do you get this plist ? as server response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/data.plist"];
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use the `NSDictionary` method `initWithContentsOfURL:` - this will download the plist specified by URL and build a dictionary from it in one go. Be advised it is a blocking call, for other options and how to avoid blocking start with the documentation for `initWithContentsOfURL:` and explore.